# SQLAlchemy join with association tables

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy

In a Flask app that uses SQLAlchemy, I have tables for users and assets. The users belong to zero to multiple groups, and the access to each asset is allowed to zero to several of these groups. These relationships are modeled with association tables (the basic structure is shown below). I can query the database and the association tables work as intended.

The part where I am struggling is to, given a user, retrieve the assets that this user is allowed to access. I understand that I need to join on groups.

In SQL, the following statement gives the result that I need:

```
select * from user as u 
  join association_user_group as aug on u.id == aug.user_id 
  join association_asset_group as aag on aag.group_id = aug.group_id
  where username='some_name';
```

However, I can't figure out how to translate this to Flask-SQLAlchemy, leveraging its benefits (which I like in many contexts).

For simplicity, let's assume the user under consideration is `User.query.first()` (in my code I have a reference to this object).

The basic database definition is as follows:

```
association_user_group = db.Table(
    'association_user_group',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('group_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'))
)

association_asset_group = db.Table(
    'association_asset_group',
    db.Column('asset_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('asset.id')),
    db.Column('group_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'))
)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...

class Asset(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'asset'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...

class Group(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'group'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...

    users = db.relationship(
        'User',
        secondary=association_user_group,
        backref=db.backref('groups', lazy='dynamic'))
    asset = db.relationship(
        'Asset',
        secondary=association_asset_group,
        backref=db.backref('groups', lazy='dynamic'))
```

**Update**: In the meanwhile, the following kind of works, but it does not make use of the `db.relationship`s defined in the classes, which seems like a shame:

```
db.session.query(association_asset_group) \
          .join(association_user_group,
                association_user_group.c.group_id
                == association_asset_group.c.group_id) \
          .filter(association_user_group.c.user_id == u.id)
```

Comment: Could you explain me quick (maybe in chat conversation) What the benefits are? Because this is exactly why I don't use Flask-SQLAlchemy, I know how to query it but don't get the Flask-SQLAlchemy syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the job:

```
q = db.session.query(Asset) \
              .join(Group, User.groups) \
              .join(Asset, Group.assets) \
              .filter(User.id == u.id) \
              .distinct()
```

But I have to say that I find it difficult to grasp the glue that flask-sqlalchemy provides under the hood (and when not).